# how to get image size from opencv node.js library

Tags: node.js, opencv

I'm using the node.js open cv library and I was wondering how to get the image width and height from what looks like a Matrix object

```
cv.readImage("./sample.jpg", function(err, im){
  var width = im.width;// this part breaks, how do I get width and height?

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the method is size()

e.g.

var width = im.size[0];

Answer (score 0):

Use the `width()` and `height()` methods on the matrix:

```
im.width()
im.height()
```

Be careful though. It's easy to forget to use the parentheses, and then you will simply be referencing the function:

```
console.log(img.width) // [Function: width]
console.log(img.width + ''); // function width() { [native code] }
```

Of course, it's easy to spot the problem in these examples, but if you're not just logging the width and height, the issues may initially go unnoticed.

Answer (score 0):

(updating to help with a lack of current opencv.js stuff on SO)

im.size() returns an object which will get you there.

```
im.size().width
im.size().height
```